# how do I change ip in netgear 7550 and do I change MAC?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Last week I bought A used Frontier Netgear 7550 modem router used local so I figured no problem setting up as access point with seperate SSID and password.
As usual the freindly not so helpfull frontier communications people didnt have the time to explain how to do this the right way so I googled. From what I understand changing the internal ip and subnet probably mac addresses should do the trick but cant seem to find where to change these that they stay changed. Basicaly I've confused myself with to much information for such a simple task.how do I go about setting up this second router? The Actual Manual Would Help Anyone Have One?